# How to schedule a cron job to run at app start up?

Tags: google-app-engine

How to schedule a cron job to run at app startup in my GAE application? I just want it to run one time at the app startup.

Comment: You could just run it from your application itself. So when it starts, it hits an endpoint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cron jobs are used for tasks that should run independently of your client application. For example, you may need a cron job to update the totals in your database at the end of a day, or to periodically clean up stale session objects, etc. Typically, you specify the time when cron jobs have to run: e.g. "every midnight".

If you need to execute a task when your application loads, you can simply execute it from your application.